# how to write a contract to set a reward for players and they claim the reward?

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens

I want to create a contract to give the players rewards and they claim their rewards.

It seems everything is ok!

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Rewards is Ownable {
    IERC20 public rewardsToken;

    mapping(address => uint) public rewards;

    constructor(address _rewardsToken) {
        rewardsToken = IERC20(_rewardsToken);
    }

    function setReward(address account,uint256 amount)  public onlyOwner  {
        rewards[account] = amount;
    }

    function claimReward() public{
        uint256 reward = rewards[msg.sender];
        rewards[msg.sender] = 0;
        rewardsToken.transfer(msg.sender, reward*10**18);
    }
}
```

but I don't know why when I claim the reward nothing happens and I have this errors.

[image]

I have enough ERC20 tokens

[image]

Comment: Does the contract have enough balance in the ERC20 token contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh Boy, I forgot to send the tokens to my contract!
that's why It didn't work!

[image]

so after I send the tokens It worked correctly

[image]